# Angular casting HttpClient response - class or interface

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I saw two methods to convert a response to our custom data model.

**Interface**

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  more_complex_object: // so I am not sure how do this in right way. pass here another interface 
  //or just a object like {id: '', name: ''}. I show how to do this in class way...
}
```

And in service:

```
return this.http.get<User>...
```

And its fine, no need to do something more.

**Class**

```
export interface Deserializable {
  deserialize(input: any): this;
}

export class ComplexModel implements Deserializable {
  field1: string;
  field2: number;
  field3: number;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
}

export class User implements Deserializable {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 complex: ComplexModel;

 deserialize(input: any): this {
   Object.assign(this, input);
   this.complex = new ComplexModel().deserialize(input.complex));
   return this;
 }
}
```

And in service

```
return this.http.get('/users/id/').pipe(
  map(user => new User().deserialize(user))
);
```

As we can see in class method we must manually creating a object. Its fine with object like above, but when we have more complex object, or array of object we must do something like this:

```
return this.http.get('/users').pipe(
  map(users => {
    if (users instanceof Array) { // <- to avoid 'object has no method map' error
      return users.map(user => {
        return new User().deserialize(user);
      });
    }
  })
);
```

In class way we have much more complex code. And finally, the questions:

Any idea how do it as best as possible? 
Which methods is the best for you and why?

Interface-way looks more beautiful, but we don't have 'a real object' so we can't use class-methods, etc, right?

In class-way we get a real object, but is it so much needed?

Comment: check my answer hot that helps you out

Comment: updated answer hope that helps you , let me know if you need more thlep

Comment: is that worked for you , have you tried out ?

Answer (score 5):

There is an explanation for this in the book: **"Angular Up and Running"** by Shyam Seshadri. 
I am quoting directly from the book Ch9 Making HTTP Calls in Angular p.178:

"*One important thing to note is that the HttpClient can give you type-assurance
across your code. We leverage this feature in the getStocks() and the toggleFavor
ite() methods.
One effect of this is that we need to change our stock.ts from a TypeScript class to a
TypeScript interface. 
Why is this? While we don’t need to, Angular does a simple typecast of the response body into the type we have defined. But TypeScript (and
ECMAScript underneath it) has no nice and easy way to convert a simple plain-old
JavaScript object into a prototypical JavaScript/TypeScript class object.
This means
that while our response from StockService will have all the properties of the class
Stock, it would not have the functions (in particular, isPositiveChange()) available.
We could write a converter, but it is only worth it in very specific cases. It is easier to
simply leverage TypeScript for type safety and work with other ways of encapsulation
(either at a component level, or maybe as an Angular service)."*

**Please refer to the book for more explanation**

Answer (score 0):

I use interfaces. Haven't yet used classes in Angular. There is a good article on this issue: [Classes vs Interfaces in TypeScript](https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript) Maybe reading it will help you to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface UserModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  more_complex_object: MoreComplexObject; // your MoreComplexObject interface
  comments: Comment[]; // your Comment interface
}
```

As you see above, you can nest interfaces together to create complex data types according to your business need.

For the 'real-object' question, why don't you create a class that takes your **UserModel** model from constructor?

```
class AppUser {
    constructor(private userModel: UserModel) {}

    someMethod() {
        // use this.userModel for logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are making use of `httpClient` then you can just do this

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data=> this.users= data);
```

means to say there is no need o deserialize logic , as it under the hood map your response to your object type.

```
export interface user {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 complex: ComplexModel;
}

export interface ComplexModel {
 field1: string;
  field2: number;
  field3: number;
}
```

this is working for me very well, if you do make use of interface , then you can create service classes seperatly which can work on your object ex.

```
export class ComplexModleManager() {
  complexObj : ComplexModle;
  constructor(private obj: ComplexModle) {
    this.complexObj = obj;
  }

  method1(){
   Console.log(complexObj.prop1);
  }     
}
```

this way you seperate out you Pain Object and Implementation logic which work on that pain object.